# MFC DestroyWindow results in crash

Tags: c++, mfc, crash

I'm having an issue with MFC. Whenever I call DestroyWindow on my modeless dialog, I crash with an unhandled exception in `AfxThrowInvalidArgException`.

Checking the callstack, it crashes on like `1055` in `wincore.cpp`:

`ENSURE(pMap != NULL);`

In case it's relevant, this is how I create the modeless window:

```
Dialogs::WelcomeDialog = new CRCChatWelcomeDlg( );
m_pMainWnd = Dialogs::WelcomeDialog;
Dialogs::WelcomeDialog->Create( DialogRCChatWelcome, CWnd::GetDesktopWindow( ) );

if ( pShellManager != nullptr )
    delete pShellManager;

MSG Message;
while ( GetMessage( &Message, Dialogs::WelcomeDialog->m_hWnd, 0, 0 ) ) {
    TranslateMessage( &Message );
    DispatchMessage( &Message );
}

Dialogs::MainMenuDialog = new CRCChatMainMenuDlg( );
m_pMainWnd = Dialogs::MainMenuDialog;
Dialogs::MainMenuDialog->Create( DialogRCChatMainMenu );

while ( GetMessage( &Message, Dialogs::MainMenuDialog->m_hWnd, 0, 0 ) ) {
    TranslateMessage( &Message );
    DispatchMessage( &Message );
}
```

And I destroy it like this:

```
Dialogs::WelcomeDialog->DestroyWindow( );
```

Comment: "Checking the callstack, it crashes on like 1055 in wincore.cpp:".  Q: Could you please post the actual error message and stack traceback?  ALSO: Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zba4hah.aspx and here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wddd3ztw(v=vs.85)

Comment: The error message is the following:
`Unhandled exception at 0x76F01812 in RCChatClient.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CInvalidArgException at memory location 0x036EF9A8.`

[Callstack](https://forceinline.pw/i/01d47.png)

Edit: I've figured out that it doesn't crash whenever I call it inside any of the dialog functions, but calling it outside causes a crash.

Comment: You are probably running that dialog on a separate thread, that isn't initialized for use by MFC. MFC keeps its internal bookkeeping information in thread-local storage that needs to be initialized. Simple solution: Keep your UI on a single thread.

Comment: Is there a way I can close the window from outside of the thread? I'm running event handlers which are global and implementing them into the class wouldn't be too good of an idea.

Comment: Q: Can I call DestroyWindow *OUTSIDE* of the thread?  A: NO.  IInspectable explained why.  ALTERNATIVE: Send the dialog a message telling it to close itself.

Comment: The documentation for [DestroyWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroywindow) is unusually explicit here: *"A thread cannot use DestroyWindow to destroy a window created by a different thread."*

Comment: Perhaps unrelated, but you might want `NULL` not `CWnd::GetDesktopWindow`: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040224-00/?p=40493